# React-hook-form doesn't display the errors

Tags: next.js, react-hook-form

I'm using:
"@chakra-ui/next-js": "^2.2.0",
"@chakra-ui/react": "^2.8.2",
"@emotion/react": "^11.11.3",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
"dayjs": "^1.11.10",
"firebase": "^10.8.0",
"framer-motion": "^11.0.5",
"next": "14.1.0",
"react": "^18",
"react-big-calendar": "^1.10.1",
"react-dom": "^18",
"react-hook-form": "^7.50.1"

```
import { Modal, ModalOverlay, ModalContent, ModalHeader,
    ModalFooter, ModalBody, ModalCloseButton, useDisclosure,
    Select, Box, Text, FormControl, FormLabel, FormErrorMessage, Input, Button } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from 'react-hook-form';
import { Turno } from '@/lib/interfaces';


export default function ScheduleModal(){

    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        watch,
        formState: { errors },
    } = useForm<Turno>();
    const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Turno> = (data) => { console.log(data);
        console.log(errors);}
    const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();
    const [form, setForm] = useState<string | undefined>("");
    
    const show = ()=>{
        console.log(errors);
    }
    
    return  <>
                    <Modal isOpen={true} onClose={onClose} size={{base:'xs', md:'lg'}} isCentered>
                    <ModalOverlay />
                    <ModalContent>
                        <ModalHeader><Text align={'center'}>Formulario de reserva</Text></ModalHeader>
                        <ModalBody>
                            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                                <FormControl marginBottom={'4'} isRequired>
                                    <FormLabel>Horarios disponibles</FormLabel>
                                    <Select id="horario"  placeholder='Horarios' {...register("horario")}>
                                        <option value='option1'>Option 1</option>
                                        <option value='option2'>Option 2</option>
                                        <option value='option3'>Option 3</option>
                                    </Select>
                                </FormControl>

                                <FormControl  isRequired marginBottom={'4'} isInvalid={ errors.nombre ? true : false}>  
                                    <FormLabel>Nombre</FormLabel>   
                                    <Input placeholder='' {...register('nombre', {required: true})} />
                                </FormControl>

                                <FormControl isRequired marginBottom={'4'}>
                                    <FormLabel>Apellido</FormLabel>
                                    <Input placeholder='' {...register('apellido', {required: true})} />
                                    {errors.apellido && <span>El apellido es requerido</span>}
                                </FormControl>

                                <FormControl isRequired marginBottom={'4'}>
                                    <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
                                    <Input type='email' placeholder='example@mail.com' {...register('email', {required: true})} />
                                    {errors.email && <span>El email es requerido</span>}
                                </FormControl>

                                <Box display={'flex'} justifyContent={'space-around'}>
                                    <Button type='submit' onClick={show}>Reservar</Button>
                                    <Button>Cancelar</Button>
                                </Box>
                            </form>
                                                    
                        </ModalBody>
                    </ModalContent>
                </Modal>
            </>
}
```

When I submit the form data with blank fields and log the errors, it returns an empty object, even though the fields are required. It doesn't recognize the errors, so the inputs don't turn red, even though they should since FormControl has the isInvalid property.
I'm testing this on the 'nombre' Input.

I'm trying to change color of the inputs when they have errors.